# C++ Sensing Characters

Tags: c++, validation

I am making a c++ game and at one point the user has to input an int. If the player inputs a char the game glitches out.

Instead of figuring out what this glitch is I want to just sense if the player inputs a char and work it out from there.

Comment: Read everything as a string, then validate the string and convert to other data types as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using cin to get the input, the simplest solution is as follows:

```
int input;
cin >> input;
if (!cin)
    //handle char not being an int
//continue
```

The trick behind this is that cin actually goes into a failure state if it cannot convert the input into the proper type.  Depending on how your game works and what the context of the input is, however, this may not be adequate.  Obviously if you aren't using cin you'll have to check if the stream you are using has the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what form of input you are using, but if it is console-based, the following may help:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Comment: Yes it's a console application and to sense the input I am using:
cin >>

Answer (score 0):

```
int x;

cout << "Enter an integer: ";

while (true) {
  if (cin >> x) { 
      // integer          
      cout << x << " is a valid number!";
      break;
  } else { 
      // not an integer          
      cout << "Enter an integer: ";
      cin.clear();
      while (cin.get() != '\n') ;
  }
}
```